# Websphere 8.5 and Hibernate 3.2.7 User TransactionManager Error

Tags: hibernate, websphere

We have a pretty old application which uses Hibernate 3.1.3.We are upgrading to Hibernate 3.2.7(i know its still old version of hibernate , eventually we plan to move to 4.x).
i am getting this exception.We are using our custom "manager_lookup_class" which calls the Transactionmanagerfactory to get the transaction manager

```
    used by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Could not find UserTransaction in JNDI [java:comp/UserTransaction]
at org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory.getUserTransaction(JTATransactionFactory.java:172)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory.createTransaction(JTATransactionFactory.java:148)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.registerSynchronizationIfPossible(JDBCContext.java:172)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.<init>(JDBCContext.java:76)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:214)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)
at org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext.buildOrObtainSession(JTASessionContext.java:114)
at org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:80)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:591)
at com.dataaccess.utility.hibernate.impl.SessionManagerImpl.getSession(SessionManagerImpl.java:319)
at com.dataaccess.handler.hibernate.impl.HandlerAdapter.getSession(HandlerAdapter.java:83)
at com.dataaccess.handler.hibernate.impl.BatchProcessingHandlerImpl.flush(BatchProcessingHandlerImpl.java:344)
at com.dataaccess.handler.hibernate.impl.BatchProcessingHandlerImpl.batchDelete(BatchProcessingHandlerImpl.java:406)
... 34 more


   Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/UserTransaction" not found in context "java:".
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1229)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1142)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory.getUserTransaction(JTATransactionFactory.java:162)
... 46 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception speaks for itself:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/UserTransaction" not found in context "java:".
```

You are performing a jndi lookup, and the resource does not exist, at least not under that name. Double check your configuration to make sure whatever you are looking for is registered in the jndi context under the name you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.This issue is coming when I am trying to upgrade HIbernate 3.1.3 to 3.2. In the same server environment with hibernate 3.1.3 it works fine. Weird thing is i took a dumpNamespace  and "comp/UserTransaction" was not present in both cases. Looking for some more suggestions.Thanks Again